# fluent stops giving away the results of its work

Tags: prometheus, fluentd

creating metrics for access.log nginx using fluent and prometheus. The RPS is 400 requests per second, the processor is loaded at 100%, since we have a tail plugin, it is impossible to support multiple processors. When the processor is loaded at some point, the metrics stop giving out and after a time I don't understand, they turn on again (the time is random from the 1st hour to the 2nd). What can be done to ensure that metrics are given constantly? we will fasten the metrics once every 30 seconds with the help of prometheus

```
<source>
  @type prometheus
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 24224
</source>

<source>
    @type tail
    <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] \"(?<method>\w+)(?:\s+(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?:\s+\S*)?)?\" (?<status_code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?:\s"(?<referer>[^\"]*)") "(?<agent>[^\"]*)" (?<urt>[^ ]*) (?<rb>[^ ]*) $/
        time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
        keep_time_key true
        types size:integer,reqtime:float,uct:float,uht:float,urt:float
    </parse>
    tag nginx
    path /var/log/nginx/mwvsmm.mts.ru_acess.log
    pos_file /tmp/fluent_nginx.pos
</source>
<filter nginx>
    @type prometheus

  <metric>
    name nginx_size_bytes_total
    type counter
    desc nginx bytes sent
    key size
  </metric>

  <metric>
    name nginx_request_status_code_total
    type counter
    desc nginx request status code
    <labels>
      method ${method}
      path ${path}
      status_code ${status_code}
      agent ${agent}
    </labels>
  </metric>

  <metric>
    name nginx_http_request_duration_seconds
    type histogram
    desc Histogram of the total time spent on receiving the response from the upstream server.
    key urt
    <labels>
      method ${method}
      path ${path}
      status_code ${status_code}
    </labels>
  </metric>

</filter>
```